# Invisible reCaptcha iframe not showing, form stuck

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I am loading two scripts on my websites:

```
<script src="scripts/my_site.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async="" defer=""></script>
```

Where `my_site.js` looks like this:

```
... many other functions, not nested

function captachaCallback() {
    console.log("Captcha");
}

... other functions
```

Then in my form I am using:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key" data-callback="captachaCallback">Send</button>
```

Whenever I press the button, a white half-transparent overlaying empty div appears, but nothing happens (console message doesn't appear) and the form is stuck.

[image: click picture]

I am using the latest Chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apply the `data-sitekey` attribute on another tag where it will contain the captcha. Don't merge your submit button with the catcha container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a CSS setting affecting all divs on my website.

```
div { overflow: hidden; }
```

Apparently this makes the popup window with the captcha test invisible.

Removing this setting solved the problem.

Comment: I had this friking same problem bro thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting that the element is going out of the visibility. So can you try adding `data-badge="inline"` to the recaptcha element in the html

```html
<button id="btnSubmit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key" data-badge="inline" data-callback="captachaCallback">Send</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This wasn't the problem but it helped me solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm very glad that it helped. :-)

Answer (score -1):

**You're not rendering the captcha.**

The submit button is trying to verify the response of the captcha once the user completes the captcha by sending a callback to the function specified on `data-callback`. Since you haven't created the component it gets stuck in a loop.

1. The submit button cannot be the same tag where you load the CAPTCHA. You need to render the captcha in an empty tag.

*Instead of:*

```
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key" data-callback="captachaCallback">Send</button>
```

*Render it like:*

```
    <div id="captcha_element" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key" data-callback="captachaCallback"></div>
```

2. Wrap it up inside a form. You already have it, so just modify it.

Since you're specifying what function to run once the captcha is completed you don't need to worry about the submit button.

*The structure should look something like this:*

```
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      /// The other elements in your form
      /// ...
      <div id="captcha_element" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-key" data-callback="captachaCallback"></div>
      <br/>
      <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Also be sure to look up the documentation ;)

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: Thank you, but I am talking about the *invisible* recaptcha.  My code actually fits exactly the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button)